# Making game over network. Is the paintcomponent()/repaint() loop ok to use on client?

Tags: java, game-loop

So I'm making a game that connects to a server where all the calculations of x, y etc will be done using elapsed time. On the client where the graphics are displayed I'm currently using the paintcomponent() and repaint() to draw the graphics. Is it ok to use this method? Because on different computers the speed of a character moving will be different based on how fast that computer can run the paintcomponent(). Let's say I'm getting 200fps while running the game.. does that mean paintcomponent is being called 200 times a second? and for slower performing computers would the paintcomponent method be called ie 60 times a second if 60fps?
(I'm using a getframerate method to find the framrate)

GOAL: My goal is to make the game run the same on all machines, not varying based on how fast the computer is

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        if (gameState == 0) { // main menu
            menuScreen.draw(g); // draw main menu screen
        } else if (gameState == 1) { // instructions
            instrScreen.draw(g);
        } else if (gameState == 2) { // options
            optionsScreen.draw(g); // draw options screen
        } else if (gameState == 3) { // game
            man.draw(g); // test
            if (upKey) {
                man.changeDirection("UP");
                man.move();
                //outputToServer("W");
            }
            if (downKey) {
                man.changeDirection("DOWN");
                man.move();
                //outputToServer("S");
            }
            if (leftKey) {
                man.changeDirection("LEFT");
                man.move();
                //outputToServer("A");
            }
            if (rightKey) {
                man.changeDirection("RIGHT");
                man.move();
                //outputToServer("D");
            }
        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(getFrameRate(), 10, 15);
        repaint();
    }

    private String getFrameRate() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        deltaTime += currentTime - lastTimeCheck;
        lastTimeCheck = currentTime;
        frameCount++;
        if (deltaTime >= 1000) {
            frameRate = frameCount + "fps";
            frameCount = 0;
            deltaTime = 0;
        }
        return frameRate;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the limiting factor be the network?  You could always time sync the updates, so the server sends an update with some kind of time code and the clients would update around it?? I have no idea how the would actually work, just thinking out loud ;)

Comment: @MagProgrammer I'm planning on calculating the new position of every entity by using a velocity and elapsed time. I'm also going to be sending information back and forth in a timed manner like X amount of times a second. So by doing this will I be able make the game run the same on all machines?

Comment: I doubt if you'll ever get it to be exactly the same, as network lag could degrade the performance of even the most powerful machine, but providing as much information as possible to the clients to make some decisions (like you say the vector of an object) should give it a chance :P

Comment: If you are using elapsed time for movement and everything else, then how many times your `paintComponent` method is called should not matter (unless you have some logic in there that doesn't use elapsed time). I don't know what your `move` method does here, but as long as that still depends on elapsed time you are okay. But I wouldn't have paint call paint, nor would I have the user I/O logic in the paint method either. The paint method should probably just paint the latest state while not changing any itself.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove Where should I put my IO logic?

Comment: @BrianChoi Well in the game there's state. So you should probably have one method that updates the state all at once for the game, and perhaps in the end call a repaint event. This might mean having another method (since it's async from your overall game loop logic) that records user I/O since the last update, which the update method later looks at. Then when you need to draw, you can reference the latest state and simply draw what's there. You'll need to probably use a `java.util.Timer` to cause your update method to be called regularly.